# Java - Set application bundle version during export

Tags: java

So I have a String that represents the version of the program I'm working on that's static. I use it in many places which is why I made one global variable.

Question: When exporting my project as a Mac application bundle, is it possible to set the CFBundleVersion in the info.plist to that string? If not, can I set it to anything during the export or must it be done manually afterwards?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Maven resource filtering mechanism to export a variable to certain files: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html

I use it to export the current version and the date the project was built:

1. I have a file named `"release.properties"` in `"D:\workspace\...\src\main\resources"` which contains some variables

   ```
   # release version
   version=${project.version}_${svninfo.committedRevision}

   # date when the current release was built
   build_date=${buildDate}
   ```
2. In my pom.xml I have declared a set of resources that Maven will parse and fill the variables with according values

   ```
   <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>D:\workspace\...\src\test\resources</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>D:\workspace\...\src\main\resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/release.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>D:\workspace\...\src\main\resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/release.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
   </resources>
   ```

Comment: Would this require me to run the program after I export?

Comment: No as Maven will build your project and in the process will also "export" the variables to the included files. However I think you should read a thing or two about what Maven is and what it does (http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) before making any changes to your code in this direction. You might find it very useful for this and all your future projects.